# GeometryModel3D Area and Volume

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to calculate the Area and Volume for a given GeometryModel3D?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't for this class type.  You can solve this using general math, though.  See this stack overflow question:

[Volume of a 3D closed mesh car object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410525)

It seems DarenW may have a useful answer for you.

Note that your mesh must be perfectly closed for this calculation to even make sense.

Also, what is "area" of a 3D object?  Surface area?  If so, just take every triangle, find the area, and sum them...