# three.js find volume weight density

Tags: three.js

The Three.js already provides example for previewing STL object in ASCII and Binary format, however I'm wondering how could I ready the volume, weight and density of the object itself?

Any hints will be helpful especially if three.js api provides as functionality?

Thank you in advance.
Tod Canovic

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is more : How to calculate the volume of a mesh, because the weight is related to the density of your object and you are the only one to be able to know what would that mesh represent and what material it would be made of.
Concerning the mesh volume calculation, there's already an answer to this question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568551/2940964

Hope this helps