# Measuring volume of a 3D model in a DirectX 11.2 app with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, volume, directx-11, measurement

I have the next problem. I have loaded a bunch of vertices and indices from an .OBJ file (from Blender) and i need to find a way to calculate the volume of the loaded 3D model. The problem is, i can't find information about measurements anywhere on the internet. So, if anyone could point me in the right direction, i would be very greatful. If there is a tutorial or something similar, please share it with me. I am working with C++11 in a DirectX 11.2 environment, with a 2013 november edition compiler. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built-in functions for this in DirectX.

You have to implement it using the vertex/triangle coordinates.
This was answered here:
[How to calculate the volume of a 3D mesh object the surface of which is made up triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406029/how-to-calculate-the-volume-of-a-3d-mesh-object-the-surface-of-which-is-made-up)