# Calculate surface area of a 3D mesh

Tags: c, r, 3d

I have a 3D mesh defined by verteces and triangles. I have also normals of the mesh. I'd like to calculate the area of the mesh, assuming it's always closed. I found an interesting implementation of calculation of the 3D volume in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406029/how-to-calculate-the-volume-of-a-3d-mesh-object-the-surface-of-which-is-made-up), and I applied it in a C code to build a function called by R. This is the code:

```
double SignedVolumeOfTriangle(double p1X, double p1Y, double p1Z, 
        double p2X, double p2Y, double p2Z, double p3X, double p3Y, double p3Z) {
    double v321 = p3X*p2Y*p1Z;
    double v231 = p2X*p3Y*p1Z;
    double v312 = p3X*p1Y*p2Z;
    double v132 = p1X*p3Y*p2Z;
    double v213 = p2X*p1Y*p3Z;
    double v123 = p1X*p2Y*p3Z;
    return (double)(1.0/6.0)*(-v321 + v231 + v312 - v132 - v213 + v123);
}
void MeshVolume(double *X, double *Y, double *Z, int *numT, int *V1, int *V2, int *V3, double *Volume) {
    int n;          
    *Volume=0;      
    for (n=0; n<*numT; n++) {
        *Volume = *Volume + SignedVolumeOfTriangle(X[V1[n]], Y[V1[n]], Z[V1[n]], X[V2[n]], Y[V2[n]], Z[V2[n]], X[V3[n]], Y[V3[n]], Z[V3[n]]);       
    }
    *Volume = fabs(*Volume);
}
```

Neither in the question nor in the article linked I found the algorithm for calculating the Area of the mesh. Is there anybody can help me please?

Comment: Did you consult any others source? Like for example any kind a "library" ...

Comment: No, I didn't it yet. But I would to solve the problem in the most efficient (and short) way possibly without using external libraries.

Comment: ;-) With "*library*" I meant one of those places where they collect knowlegde, for example by piling up books in the old days ...

Comment: :-D I'm a medical doctor so... "libraries" that I'm used to attend talk about medicine, anatomy, physiology etc...

Comment: Try googling your question's title literally and you'll find quiet some references, then come back with your approach, and tell us the problems you are facing, if any ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a closed volume whose surface is made up by triangles. And all triangles contribute to the outer surface. right?

The surface of a triangle between points `P`, `Q` and `R` can be obtained by:

```
A = 0.5 * |PQ × PR|
  = 0.5 * |PQ| * |PR| * sin(Ɵ)
```

where

```
PQ = Q - P
PR = R - P
```

and `×` denotes the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and `Ɵ` is the angle between the vectors. (The magnitude of the resulting vector of a cross product is the area of a parallelogramme between the two original vectors. Half of that is the area of a triangle.)

Sum the aeras of all triangles. There's no need to take the absolute value, because the area can only be zero or positive. So:

```
double AreaOfTriangle(double p1X, double p1Y, double p1Z, 
        double p2X, double p2Y, double p2Z,
        double p3X, double p3Y, double p3Z)
{
    double ax = p2x - p1x;
    double ay = p2y - p1y;
    double az = p2z - p1z;
    double bx = p3x - p1x;
    double by = p3y - p1y;
    double bz = p3z - p1z;
    double cx = ay*bz - az*by;
    double cy = az*bx - ax*bz;
    double cz = ax*by - ay*bx;

    return 0.5 * sqrt(cx*cx + cy*cy + cz*cz);
}    

void MeshSurface(double *X, double *Y, double *Z,
    int *numT, int *V1, int *V2, int *V3, double *Area)
{
    int n;

    *Area = 0.0;

    for (n=0; n<*numT; n++) {
        *Area += AreaOfTriangle(X[V1[n]], Y[V1[n]], Z[V1[n]],
            X[V2[n]], Y[V2[n]], Z[V2[n]],
            X[V3[n]], Y[V3[n]], Z[V3[n]]);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you M Oehm, I cannot vote up yet but it is what I was searching for!