# Land survey data to mesh

Tags: delphi, pascal

From a topological survey of a plot of land, I have about 1000 points (X, Y, Z).

Since the measurements are taken where the topology changes, these points do not form a perfect grid but something akin to points on an imaginary mesh.

I need to calculate the volume of landfill necessary to make this plot of land flat at a given height.

I suppose I first need to generate some kind of mesh (of triangles) in order to be able to begin calculating anything.

And, that's where I am stuck: Is there an algorithm (or, even better, an implementation in Pascal) that I could use to turn these points into a triangular mesh.

Comment: I dont think that Delphi ships with such 3D functions. But there might be a comprehensive 3D processing library somewhere on the web. Have you tried anything so far? Remember, SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I haven't tried anything in code yet.Simply because I am not sure how I could generate a triangular mesh so that I could use the formula here (a straight case of solving a given matrix) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrahedron.html In other words it boils down to generating the mesh from available coordinates. [And yes, I am aware that SO is not a code wring place, but I am hoping someone will help me start off]

Comment: Maybe try asking on http://gis.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It would be nice if Delphi, or at least the FMX framework had some more geometric stuff built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangulation should be your first step, to simplify the next steps.

You *could* treat the points as 2d points during the triangulation, using the example code below, although it might not be the optimal solution for 3d points.

Anyway, after that you'll be left with a 3d object that's built up out of triangles, and calculating the surface and volume becomes simple. There are tons of examples that demonstrate how to do this.

**Volume:**
[How to calculate the volume of a 3D mesh object the surface of which is made up triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406029/how-to-calculate-the-volume-of-a-3d-mesh-object-the-surface-of-which-is-made-up)

**Surface:**
[Calculate surface area of a 3D mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312570/calculate-surface-area-of-a-3d-mesh)

To do triangulation, you can read this page:
http://paulbourke.net/papers/triangulate/

It includes a Delphi implementation of the [Delaunay triangulation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).
http://paulbourke.net/papers/triangulate/Delaunay.zip (source+exe)

The code says that you can do with the code whatever you want, as long as you keep the credits. In case the page or the zipfile ever go offline, I'll paste the contents here (it would be handy if StackOverflow let us attach files intead).

Delaunay.pas:

```
//Credit to Paul Bourke (pbourke@swin.edu.au) for the original Fortran 77 Program :))
//Conversion to Visual Basic by EluZioN (EluZioN@casesladder.com)
//Conversion from VB to Delphi6 by Dr Steve Evans (steve@lociuk.com)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//June 2002 Update by Dr Steve Evans (steve@lociuk.com): Heap memory allocation
//added to prevent stack overflow when MaxVertices and MaxTriangles are very large.
//Additional Updates in June 2002:
//Bug in InCircle function fixed. Radius r := Sqrt(rsqr).
//Check for duplicate points added when inserting new point.
//For speed, all points pre-sorted in x direction using quicksort algorithm and
//triangles flagged when no longer needed. The circumcircle centre and radius of
//the triangles are now stored to improve calculation time.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//You can use this code however you like providing the above credits remain in tact

unit Delaunay;

interface

uses Dialogs, Graphics, Forms, Types;

//Set these as applicable
Const MaxVertices = 500000;
Const MaxTriangles = 1000000;
Const ExPtTolerance = 0.000001;

//Points (Vertices)
Type dVertex = record
    x: Double;
    y: Double;
end;

//Created Triangles, vv# are the vertex pointers
Type dTriangle = record
    vv0: LongInt;
    vv1: LongInt;
    vv2: LongInt;
    PreCalc: Integer;
    xc,yc,r: Double;
end;

type TDVertex = array[0..MaxVertices] of dVertex;
type PVertex = ^TDVertex;

type TDTriangle = array[0..MaxTriangles] of dTriangle;
type PTriangle = ^TDTriangle;

type TDComplete = array [0..MaxTriangles] of Boolean;
type PComplete = ^TDComplete;

type TDEdges = array[0..2,0..MaxTriangles * 3] of LongInt;
type PEdges = ^TDEdges;

type
  TDelaunay = class
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Vertex: PVertex;
    Triangle: PTriangle;
    function InCircle(xp, yp, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3: Double;
             var xc: Double; var yc: Double; var r: Double; j: Integer): Boolean;
    Function WhichSide(xp, yp, x1, y1, x2, y2: Double): Integer;
    Function Triangulate(nvert: Integer): Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    TempBuffer: TBitmap;
    HowMany: Integer;
    tPoints: Integer; //Variable for total number of points (vertices)
    TargetForm: TForm;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;
    procedure Mesh;
    procedure Draw;
    procedure AddPoint(x,y: Integer);
    procedure ClearBackPage;
    procedure FlipBackPage;
    procedure QuickSort(var A: PVertex; Low,High: Integer);
  end;

implementation

constructor TDelaunay.Create;
begin
  //Initiate total points to 1, using base 0 causes problems in the functions
  tPoints := 1;
  HowMany:=0;
  TempBuffer:=TBitmap.Create;

  //Allocate memory for arrays
  GetMem(Vertex, sizeof(Vertex^));
  GetMem(Triangle, sizeof(Triangle^));
end;

destructor TDelaunay.Destroy;
begin
  //Free memory for arrays
  FreeMem(Vertex, sizeof(Vertex^));
  FreeMem(Triangle, sizeof(Triangle^));
end;



function TDelaunay.InCircle(xp, yp, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3: Double;
    var xc: Double; var yc: Double; var r: Double; j: Integer): Boolean;
//Return TRUE if the point (xp,yp) lies inside the circumcircle
//made up by points (x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3)
//The circumcircle centre is returned in (xc,yc) and the radius r
//NOTE: A point on the edge is inside the circumcircle
var
  eps: Double;
  m1: Double;
  m2: Double;
  mx1: Double;
  mx2: Double;
  my1: Double;
  my2: Double;
  dx: Double;
  dy: Double;
  rsqr: Double;
  drsqr: Double;
begin

  eps:= 0.000001;
  InCircle := False;

  //Check if xc,yc and r have already been calculated
  if  Triangle^[j].PreCalc=1 then
  begin
    xc := Triangle^[j].xc;
    yc := Triangle^[j].yc;
    r  := Triangle^[j].r;
    rsqr := r*r;
    dx := xp - xc;
    dy := yp - yc;
    drsqr := dx * dx + dy * dy;
  end else
  begin



  If (Abs(y1 - y2) < eps) And (Abs(y2 - y3) < eps) Then
  begin
  ShowMessage('INCIRCUM - F - Points are coincident !!');
  Exit;
  end;

  If Abs(y2 - y1) < eps Then
  begin
  m2 := -(x3 - x2) / (y3 - y2);
  mx2 := (x2 + x3) / 2;
  my2 := (y2 + y3) / 2;
  xc := (x2 + x1) / 2;
  yc := m2 * (xc - mx2) + my2;
  end
  Else If Abs(y3 - y2) < eps Then
  begin
  m1 := -(x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);
  mx1 := (x1 + x2) / 2;
  my1 := (y1 + y2) / 2;
  xc := (x3 + x2) / 2;
  yc := m1 * (xc - mx1) + my1;
  end
  Else
  begin
  m1 := -(x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);
  m2 := -(x3 - x2) / (y3 - y2);
  mx1 := (x1 + x2) / 2;
  mx2 := (x2 + x3) / 2;
  my1 := (y1 + y2) / 2;
  my2 := (y2 + y3) / 2;
    if (m1-m2)<>0 then  //se
    begin
    xc := (m1 * mx1 - m2 * mx2 + my2 - my1) / (m1 - m2);
    yc := m1 * (xc - mx1) + my1;
    end else
    begin
    xc:= (x1+x2+x3)/3;
    yc:= (y1+y2+y3)/3;
    end;

  end;

  dx := x2 - xc;
  dy := y2 - yc;
  rsqr := dx * dx + dy * dy;
  r := Sqrt(rsqr);
  dx := xp - xc;
  dy := yp - yc;
  drsqr := dx * dx + dy * dy;

  //store the xc,yc and r for later use
  Triangle^[j].PreCalc:=1;
  Triangle^[j].xc:=xc;
  Triangle^[j].yc:=yc;
  Triangle^[j].r:=r;
  end;

  If drsqr <= rsqr Then InCircle := True;

end;



Function TDelaunay.WhichSide(xp, yp, x1, y1, x2, y2: Double): Integer;
//Determines which side of a line the point (xp,yp) lies.
//The line goes from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)
//Returns -1 for a point to the left
//         0 for a point on the line
//        +1 for a point to the right
var
 equation: Double;
begin
  equation := ((yp - y1) * (x2 - x1)) - ((y2 - y1) * (xp - x1));

  If equation > 0 Then
     WhichSide := -1
  Else If equation = 0 Then
     WhichSide := 0
  Else
     WhichSide := 1;

End;



Function TDelaunay.Triangulate(nvert: Integer): Integer;
//Takes as input NVERT vertices in arrays Vertex()
//Returned is a list of NTRI triangular faces in the array
//Triangle(). These triangles are arranged in clockwise order.
var

  Complete: PComplete;
  Edges: PEdges;
  Nedge: LongInt;

  //For Super Triangle
  xmin: Double;
  xmax: Double;
  ymin: Double;
  ymax: Double;
  xmid: Double;
  ymid: Double;
  dx: Double;
  dy: Double;
  dmax: Double;

  //General Variables
  i : Integer;
  j : Integer;
  k : Integer;
  ntri : Integer;
  xc : Double;
  yc : Double;
  r : Double;
  inc : Boolean;
begin

  //Allocate memory
  GetMem(Complete, sizeof(Complete^));
  GetMem(Edges, sizeof(Edges^));


//Find the maximum and minimum vertex bounds.
//This is to allow calculation of the bounding triangle
xmin := Vertex^[1].x;
ymin := Vertex^[1].y;
xmax := xmin;
ymax := ymin;
  For i := 2 To nvert do
  begin
  If Vertex^[i].x < xmin Then xmin := Vertex^[i].x;
  If Vertex^[i].x > xmax Then xmax := Vertex^[i].x;
  If Vertex^[i].y < ymin Then ymin := Vertex^[i].y;
  If Vertex^[i].y > ymax Then ymax := Vertex^[i].y;
  end;

dx := xmax - xmin;
dy := ymax - ymin;
If dx > dy Then
    dmax := dx
Else
    dmax := dy;

xmid := Trunc((xmax + xmin) / 2);
ymid := Trunc((ymax + ymin) / 2);

//Set up the supertriangle
//This is a triangle which encompasses all the sample points.
//The supertriangle coordinates are added to the end of the
//vertex list. The supertriangle is the first triangle in
//the triangle list.

Vertex^[nvert + 1].x := (xmid - 2 * dmax);
Vertex^[nvert + 1].y := (ymid - dmax);
Vertex^[nvert + 2].x := xmid;
Vertex^[nvert + 2].y := (ymid + 2 * dmax);
Vertex^[nvert + 3].x := (xmid + 2 * dmax);
Vertex^[nvert + 3].y := (ymid - dmax);
Triangle^[1].vv0 := nvert + 1;
Triangle^[1].vv1 := nvert + 2;
Triangle^[1].vv2 := nvert + 3;
Triangle^[1].Precalc := 0;

Complete[1] := False;
ntri := 1;

//Include each point one at a time into the existing mesh
For i := 1 To nvert do
begin
  Nedge := 0;
    //Set up the edge buffer.
    //If the point (Vertex(i).x,Vertex(i).y) lies inside the circumcircle then the
    //three edges of that triangle are added to the edge buffer.
    j := 0;
      repeat
        j := j + 1;
        If Complete^[j] <> True Then
        begin
            inc := InCircle(Vertex^[i].x, Vertex^[i].y, Vertex^[Triangle^[j].vv0].x,
                            Vertex^[Triangle^[j].vv0].y, Vertex^[Triangle^[j].vv1].x,
                            Vertex^[Triangle^[j].vv1].y, Vertex^[Triangle^[j].vv2].x,
                            Vertex^[Triangle^[j].vv2].y, xc, yc, r,j);
            //Include this if points are sorted by X
            If (xc + r) < Vertex[i].x Then  //
               complete[j] := True          //
            Else                            //
            If inc Then
            begin
                Edges^[1, Nedge + 1] := Triangle^[j].vv0;
                Edges^[2, Nedge + 1] := Triangle^[j].vv1;
                Edges^[1, Nedge + 2] := Triangle^[j].vv1;
                Edges^[2, Nedge + 2] := Triangle^[j].vv2;
                Edges^[1, Nedge + 3] := Triangle^[j].vv2;
                Edges^[2, Nedge + 3] := Triangle^[j].vv0;
                Nedge := Nedge + 3;
                Triangle^[j].vv0 := Triangle^[ntri].vv0;
                Triangle^[j].vv1 := Triangle^[ntri].vv1;
                Triangle^[j].vv2 := Triangle^[ntri].vv2;
                Triangle^[j].PreCalc:=Triangle^[ntri].PreCalc;
                Triangle^[j].xc:=Triangle^[ntri].xc;
                Triangle^[j].yc:=Triangle^[ntri].yc;
                Triangle^[j].r:=Triangle^[ntri].r;
                Triangle^[ntri].PreCalc:=0;
                Complete^[j] := Complete^[ntri];
                j := j - 1;
                ntri := ntri - 1;
            End;
        End;
    until j>=ntri;

// Tag multiple edges
// Note: if all triangles are specified anticlockwise then all
// interior edges are opposite pointing in direction.
    For j := 1 To Nedge - 1 do
    begin
        If Not (Edges^[1, j] = 0) And Not (Edges^[2, j] = 0) Then
        begin
            For k := j + 1 To Nedge do
            begin
                If Not (Edges^[1, k] = 0) And Not (Edges^[2, k] = 0) Then
                begin
                    If Edges^[1, j] = Edges^[2, k] Then
                    begin
                        If Edges^[2, j] = Edges^[1, k] Then
                         begin
                            Edges^[1, j] := 0;
                            Edges^[2, j] := 0;
                            Edges^[1, k] := 0;
                            Edges^[2, k] := 0;
                         End;
                     End;
                End;
            end;
        End;
    end;

//  Form new triangles for the current point
//  Skipping over any tagged edges.
//  All edges are arranged in clockwise order.
    For j := 1 To Nedge do
    begin
            If Not (Edges^[1, j] = 0) And Not (Edges^[2, j] = 0) Then
            begin
                ntri := ntri + 1;
                Triangle^[ntri].vv0 := Edges^[1, j];
                Triangle^[ntri].vv1 := Edges^[2, j];
                Triangle^[ntri].vv2 := i;
                Triangle^[ntri].PreCalc:=0;
                Complete^[ntri] := False;
            End;
    end;
end;

//Remove triangles with supertriangle vertices
//These are triangles which have a vertex number greater than NVERT
i:= 0;
repeat
  i := i + 1;
  If (Triangle^[i].vv0 > nvert) Or (Triangle^[i].vv1 > nvert) Or (Triangle^[i].vv2 > nvert) Then
  begin
     Triangle^[i].vv0 := Triangle^[ntri].vv0;
     Triangle^[i].vv1 := Triangle^[ntri].vv1;
     Triangle^[i].vv2 := Triangle^[ntri].vv2;
     i := i - 1;
     ntri := ntri - 1;
  End;
until i>=ntri;

Triangulate := ntri;

  //Free memory
  FreeMem(Complete, sizeof(Complete^));
  FreeMem(Edges, sizeof(Edges^));
End;


procedure TDelaunay.Mesh;
begin
  QuickSort(Vertex,1,tPoints-1);
  If tPoints > 3 Then
  HowMany := Triangulate(tPoints-1); //'Returns number of triangles created.
end;



procedure TDelaunay.Draw;
var
  //variable to hold how many triangles are created by the triangulate function
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Clear the form canvas
  ClearBackPage;

  TempBuffer.Canvas.Brush.Color := clTeal;
  //Draw the created triangles
  if (HowMany > 0) then
  begin
    For i:= 1 To HowMany do
    begin
    TempBuffer.Canvas.Polygon([Point(Trunc(Vertex^[Triangle^[i].vv0].x), Trunc(Vertex^[Triangle^[i].vv0].y)),
                                  Point(Trunc(Vertex^[Triangle^[i].vv1].x), Trunc(Vertex^[Triangle^[i].vv1].y)),
                                  Point(Trunc(Vertex^[Triangle^[i].vv2].x), Trunc(Vertex^[Triangle^[i].vv2].y))]);
    end;
  end;

  FlipBackPage;
end;

procedure TDelaunay.AddPoint(x,y: Integer);
var
i, AE: Integer;
begin

  //Check for duplicate points
  AE:=0;
  i:=1;
  while i<tPoints do
  begin
  If (Abs(x-Vertex^[i].x) < ExPtTolerance) and
     (Abs(y-Vertex^[i].y) < ExPtTolerance) Then AE:=1;
  Inc(i);
  end;

  if AE=0 then
  begin
  //Set Vertex coordinates where you clicked the pic box
  Vertex^[tPoints].x := x;
  Vertex^[tPoints].y := y;
  //Increment the total number of points
  tPoints := tPoints + 1;
  end;

end;




procedure TDelaunay.ClearBackPage;
begin
  TempBuffer.Height:=TargetForm.Height;
  TempBuffer.Width:=TargetForm.Width;
  TempBuffer.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSilver;
  TempBuffer.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,TargetForm.Width,TargetForm.Height));
end;

procedure TDelaunay.FlipBackPage;
var
  ARect : TRect;
begin
  ARect := Rect(0,0,TargetForm.Width,TargetForm.Height);
  TargetForm.Canvas.CopyRect(ARect, TempBuffer.Canvas, ARect);
end;


procedure TDelaunay.QuickSort(var A: PVertex; Low,High: Integer);
//Sort all points by x
  procedure DoQuickSort(var A: PVertex; iLo, iHi: Integer);
  var
    Lo, Hi: Integer;
    Mid: Double;
    T: dVertex;
  begin
    Lo := iLo;
    Hi := iHi;
    Mid := A^[(Lo + Hi) div 2].x;
    repeat
      while A^[Lo].x < Mid do Inc(Lo);
      while A^[Hi].x > Mid do Dec(Hi);
      if Lo <= Hi then
      begin
        T := A^[Lo];
        A^[Lo] := A^[Hi];
        A^[Hi] := T;
        Inc(Lo);
        Dec(Hi);
      end;
    until Lo > Hi;
    if Hi > iLo then DoQuickSort(A, iLo, Hi);
    if Lo < iHi then DoQuickSort(A, Lo, iHi);
  end;
begin
  DoQuickSort(A, Low, High);
end;

end.
```

Unit1.dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 217
  Top = 172
  Width = 696
  Height = 480
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -10
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnMouseDown = FormMouseDown
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

Unit1.pas:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Delaunay, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
  public
    TheMesh: TDelaunay;
  end;

var Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TheMesh:= TDelaunay.Create;
  TheMesh.TargetForm:=Form1;
  Form1.Caption:='Click on the form!';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  TheMesh.AddPoint(x,y); //add a point to the mesh
  TheMesh.Mesh;          //triangulate the mesh
  TheMesh.Draw;   //draw the mesh on the forms canvas

  Form1.Caption:='Points: '+IntToStr(TheMesh.tPoints-1)+
                 '  Triangles: '+IntToStr(TheMesh.HowMany);
end;

end.
```

project1.dpr

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms, Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},  Delaunay in 'Delaunay.pas';

{$R *.res}    
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

You'll still have to implement some stuff yourself, but this might be a start. Let us know if you get stuck somewhere.

Finally, you can always cheat, and convert the mesh to a format that a program like 3dsmax can read, and there you can simply see the volume of a selected 3d object. :) Might not be an option if you need to repeat this task.

Comment: Thank you. This is all the information (and code) I needed. Accepted as answer with gratitude..

Answer (score 1):

**Not direct answer to your question but instead an alternate approach for getting the final results.**

I don't think that creating triangular mesh would bring you much closer to the final result.

I would use a different approach and instead of creating a triangular mesh I would create a `Heightmap`.

Heightmap is an image where each pixel represents elevation at certain point in the map. Heightmaps are usually greyscale images which means that each pixel can store 256 different possible elevations.

Once you have heightmap generated it is quite easy to calculate the available volume of your landfill. How?

Let's assume that each pixel can store elevation from 0 to 256 meters and that each pixel represents one square meter of land.

So now you just have to calculate the difference between desired height and the height of a specific pixel by which you can get amount of dirt that can be dumped on the square meter plot of land that is represented by that specific pixel. And you do this for every pixel.

The code would something like this:

```
var AvailableDumpSpace: UInt64;
    HeightMap: TBitmap; //8 bit Greyscale bitmap
    X,Y: Integer;
    DesiredHeight: Integer;

for Y := 0 to HeightMap.Height-1 do
begin
  for X := 0 to HeightMap.Width-1 do
  begin
    //Land is lower so it can be filled
    if DesiredHeight > HeightMap[X,Y].Color then
      AvailableDumpSpace := AvailalbeDumpSpace + (DesiredHeight - HeightMap[X,Y].Color
    //Land is higher so it must be bulldozed which would result in more dirt
    //that needs to be dumped somewhere
    else if DesiredHeight < HeightMap[X,Y].Color then
      AvailableDumpSpace := AvailableDumpSpace - (HeightMap[X,Y].Color - DesiredHeight);
  end;
end;
```

As you see I also added ability to take into account that leveling of ground that is higher than the desired height would actually resulted in excess dirt that needs to be dumped somewhere. And it probably would be dumped in the landfill and thus decrease its capacity.

Comment: I am not sure how this would solve the problem. If it did, it wouldn't be hard to create my own class that replaces the TBitmap so that I could use non-integer (i.e. float) values. The land area I am talking about is 8000 m2 while the number of points is 1000. Trouble is, these points are taken very sparsely. Such that, sometimes they are denser than 4m apart other times they are more that 20m apart.