# How to calculate volume of a 3D mesh from wavefront .obj file?

Tags: math, 3d, mesh, .obj

I am trying to parse wavefront .obj file. From wikipedia I learned it's format specification. I am interested in volume analysis. Before that i worked in .stl files. I can compute volume of tetrahedron by using dot and cross product. In .stl files triangular faces' coordinates are given 
i.e.

- point1(x1, y1, z1),
- point2(x2, y2, z2),
- point3(x3, y3, z3).

But in wavefront .obj files :
Each face can contain three or more vertices.
f v1 v2 v3 v4 ..... like this. I do not know how to calculate the volume now. Because my understanding is, it will produce a polyhedron. Any idea will be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented the solution presented in this post and it works fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406029/how-to-calculate-the-volume-of-a-3d-mesh-object-the-surface-of-which-is-made-up

Comment: @Nic I also looked at the very post. In fact it is a famous one. But my problem is not about calculating triangular faced object's volume, Rather non-planer shaped object's volume consisting more than 3 points. Hence not triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Each polygonal face can be subdivided in triangles and therefore used for tetrahedrons. If you are lucky enough, you can find polygons with 4 vertices only (easy to be decomposed in two triangles on the fly). For polygons with more than 4 vertices you need a triangulation algorithm to decompose the planar polygon in triangles. You can check [Ear Clipping](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf) for example.

Comment: Following your link and couple of more google search i found a code snippet.
<code>
 vertex v1, v2, v3;
vector<triangle> newtris;

v1 = polygon.vertices[0];
for ( i=0; i < polygon.sides-2; ++i )
{
v2=polygon.vertices[ i+1 ];
v3=polygon.vertices[ i+2 ];

newtris.push_back( triangle( v0, v1, v2 ) );
}
<code>
This should work, right ?

Comment: Polygon can have many vertices and be non-convex. This is why a recommended a triangulator.