# Intersection of meshes generated by numpy (pyvista)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyvista, pymeshlab

I'm trying to create from scratch some 3D geometry from some points in the plane that are rotated around the centre (0,0,0) and then this same geometry I move it 3 units in x,y,z respectively. I am using pyvista to modelate this geometries and try to find the intersection between geometry 1 and 2. I have wrote the following code.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyvista as pv
plt.close("all")

corners = np.array([[0,0],[5,0],[5,10],[7,12],[7,15],[0,15]])
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)

#geometry 1
xx = np.outer(corners[:,0], np.cos(phi))
yy = np.outer(corners[:,0], np.sin(phi))
__, zz = np.meshgrid(phi, corners[:,1])

#geometry 2
xx_1 = xx+3
yy_1 = yy+3
zz_1 = zz+3

# =============================================================================
# Point cloud creation 
# =============================================================================
x = xx.flatten()
y = yy.flatten()
z = zz.flatten()

points = np.array([x,y,z]).T
points = np.unique(points, axis=0)

# =============================================================================
# PolyData body creation
# =============================================================================

point_cloud_1 = pv.PolyData(points)
point_cloud_2 = pv.PolyData(points+3)
# =============================================================================
# Testing mesh creation methods
# =============================================================================
# Generating meshes with diverse methods 
mesh_1 = point_cloud_1.delaunay_2d()
mesh_2 = point_cloud_2.delaunay_2d()

# mesh_1 = point_cloud_1.delaunay_3d(alpha = 6)
# mesh_2 = point_cloud_2.delaunay_3d(alpha = 6)

# mesh_1 = point_cloud_1.reconstruct_surface()
# mesh_2 = point_cloud_2.reconstruct_surface()

# mesh_1 = pv.StructuredGrid(xx,yy,zz)
# mesh_2 = pv.StructuredGrid(xx_1,yy_1,zz_1)

plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(mesh_1,show_edges=True,  color="red", point_size=5)
plotter.add_mesh(mesh_2,show_edges=True, color="blue", point_size=5)
```

[image: Geometry obtained in matplotlib]

Geometry obtained in matplotlib

[image: Geometry obtained by delaunay_2d()]

Geometry obtained by delaunay_2d()

[image: Geometry obtained by delaunay_3d(alpha=6)]

Geometry obtained by delaunay_3d(alpha=6

[image: Geometry obtained by reconstruct_surface()]

Geometry obtained by reconstruct_surface()

[image: Geometry obtained by StructuredGrid]

Geometry obtained by StructuredGrid

```
intersection = mesh_1.boolean_intersection(mesh_2)
```

The best approaches considering what I have achieved are the delaunay_3d and StructuredGrid. In my research maybe pymeshlab could be also an option, but the most similar question founded is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370374/boolean-geometry-subtraction-of-3d-meshes/74749465#74749465) . In this case the meshes are already built up. Another aspect is the boolean operation is not possible because those geometries are not triangular meshes. I have been looking for information for some weeks and I have not been able to understand how can I perform this operation.